# Bubble Sort algo sorting items in descending order - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

Following is my code for bubble sort, which is sorting the array in descending only. However I am trying it to sort by ascending only. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
var a = [53, 11, 34, 12, 18];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if(a[i] > a[j]) {
            var temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;        
        }
    }
}

console.log("Array:: ", a);
```

Comment: The only operation that compares items is `a[i] > a[j]`. How might you reverse the relationship?

Comment: @Ryan I think what trincot suggested is a better way than your swapping comment

Comment: Mmm, I skimmed the question and didn’t notice you weren’t actually doing bubble sort. There would typically be a `sorted` flag that gets reset at the beginning of the loop and set if a swap is performed, for a Θ(n) best case instead of Θ(n²). What you have here is an incorrect implementation of *selection* sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a proper bubble sort, the inner loop should not iterate all values each time. Your inner loop must start at `i+1`:

```
for(var j=i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
```

```js
var a = [53, 11, 34, 12, 18];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(var j=i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
        if(a[i] > a[j]) {
            var temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;        
        }
    }
}

console.log("Array:: ", a);
```

Comment: Ahh yes this is the case...and best solution rather than changing the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Just swap make the statement `a[i] < a[j]` instead of `a[i] > a[j]`

```
var a = [53, 11, 34, 12, 18];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if(a[i] < a[j]) {
            var temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;        
        }
    }
}

console.log("Array:: ", a);
```

Comment: Btw try to only do it with Ryan's advice first... I was a bit too eager to give the full answer here :)